# Contextual output using decorators

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to give contextual output, and I would have thought a decorator is the place to put this logic. However, I can't access my `current_user` method in a decorator.

Right now, I'm doing this in a view:

```
<% if current_user == @user %> Your <% else "#{@user.username}'s" end %> profile
```

and it seems a bit messy. I want to do it in a draper. This is my first step towards this goal:

```
class UserDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all

  include SessionsHelper        

  def is_owner?
    current_user === model
  end

end
```

my sessions helper:

```
module SessionsHelper

    def current_user=(user)
        @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
        remember_token = User.hash(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
    end
end
```

however, this results in:

```
undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<UserDecorator:0x000000054ad2d8>

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:9:in `current_user'
app/decorators/user_decorator.rb:9:in `is_owner?'
app/views/users/show.html.erb:37:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2600317495065048162_44417960'
```

I could include the module that contains the `cookies` method (what part of rails is this by the way?), but I can't help thinking I'm doing it wrong if I need to include all of this stuff?

I also want to do this in a draper:

```
<% if current_user == @user || current_user.is_admin? %> 
   <!-- buttons leading to private functionality -->
<% end %>
```

but don't know how to output complex multi-lined html like a collection of buttons. **Should I create a partial of this secret section of html and render a partial from the decorator?**

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `Draper` gem and want to use helper methods inside a decorator, then you should call them with `h.`. So in your case it would be `h.current_user`

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are using `current_user` helper inside the `UserDecorator` is the problem. As per the [documentation](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#accessing-helpers), in order to access helpers inside Draper decorator class, you can use `h` method.

**e.g.**

```
def is_owner?
  h.current_user
end
```

If you do not wish to use `h` method all the time, you can simply include `Draper::LazyHelpers`. That way, your code as it stands now will work.

```
class UserDecorator < ApplicationDecorator
  delegate_all
  include Draper::LazyHelpers # Add this line

  include SessionsHelper        

  def is_owner?
    current_user === model
  end

end
```